# Twitter, get tweets from user in a specific day

Tags: api, twitter

I want to get all tweets of a user in a day using twitter api in php.
I read that i can use search method but there is a limit of seven days.
I want to get tweets of two month ago.
Is it possible in some way?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [`user_timeline`](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/user_timeline) method to fetch up to 3200 of the user's most recent Tweets. If that includes Tweets from two months ago, you are OK, but busy accounts may have Tweeted more often than that over a period of time.

There is no way to search for Tweets further back than 7 days using the public API.